# Could someone please explain me how this particular line works

Tags: data-structures, bit-manipulation

I was trying to solve this problem on leetcode : https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-product-of-word-lengths/
I tried many approaches but was not able to come up with an efficient solution.
After, going through the discussion portal I found this solution.
Could someone please tell me how this line works:
`value[i] |= 1 << (tmp.charAt(j) - 'a');`

This is the code:

```
    if (words == null || words.length == 0)
        return 0;
    int len = words.length;
    int[] value = new int[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        String tmp = words[i];
        value[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < tmp.length(); j++) {
            value[i] |= 1 << (tmp.charAt(j) - 'a');
        }
    }
    int maxProduct = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
            if ((value[i] & value[j]) == 0 && (words[i].length() * words[j].length() > maxProduct))
                maxProduct = words[i].length() * words[j].length();
        }
    return maxProduct;
}
```

Comment: It looks like Java to me. Would you be so kind and update the tags with the corresponding programming language?

Answer (score 0):

```
value[i] |= 1 << (tmp.charAt(j) - 'a');
```

- `(tmp.charAt(j) - 'a')` uses the ASCII values of the characters and does a subtraction returning an integer. E.g. `'a'-'a'` is `0`, `'b'-'a'` is '1', `'c'-'a'` is `2`, ... It is basically arithmetic. Note that the result is an integer and you can see it is like indexing the character (which is used for the bit place in a bit pattern).
- `1 << n` means shift `n` times to left inserting `0`s. E.g. if `1` is a 32 bit number `000000..00001` and you do `1 << 3` you will get `000000...01000`. You have the index of the character and you can now shift to the index for that character, in this just mentioned example you must have had a `d` since you shifted `3` times.
- `a |= b` is equivalent to `a = a | b`
  It is used to combine with the OR operation the bit pattern of the word.
- [Operators have precedences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) that will determine the order of operations. In this case (I suppose Java) one can figure out the operator precedences of `|=` (assignment) and `<<` (shift). By putting an expression in parentheses you give that expression higher precedence (as you know it from math I guess).

So in order the expression is evaluated as follows:

1. `(tmp.charAt(j) - 'a')` (calculate the index of the `j-th` character; let's call the index X)
2. `1 << X` (calculates the bis position for that character; let's call the result Y)
3. `value[i] |= Y`, which is equivalent to `value[i] = value[i] | Y`
   (add the bit position to the bit pattern)

The idea is the following:

- You have a list of words. So you iterate over that list.
- You keep an array `value` which has a size equal to the number of words you iterate over. So `value[i]` is the bit pattern for the `word[i]`
- you iterate over the characters of each word and store the bit pattern for that word (the part your question is about is to get the bit place in that bit pattern for the character of the word). It is ORed (`|`) so that the bit pattern represents all characters found in that word.
- When you have a bit pattern for one word and another bit pattern for another word, you can AND (`&`) them: when the result `0` then this means the words have not characters in common, otherwise they have at least one character in common.